# simplify code for finding Armstrong number

Tags: matlab

> A [armstrong number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) is a number that is the sum of its own digits
>   each raised to the power of the number of digits.

My code shown below for finding 7 digits Armstrong Number, The reason to use `bsxfun`because it's pretty fast, but it's only accept three parameter(Mathematica's similar function `Outer` can accept multiple parameters). How can I make my code more compact?

```
tic
m1=(1:9).^7;
m=(0:9).^7;
r1=bsxfun(@plus, m1', m);
r2=bsxfun(@plus, r1, reshape(m,1,1,[]));
r3=bsxfun(@plus, r2, reshape(m,1,1,1,[]));
r4=bsxfun(@plus, r3, reshape(m,1,1,1,1,[]));
r5=bsxfun(@plus, r4, reshape(m,1,1,1,1,1,[]));
r6=bsxfun(@plus, r5, reshape(m,1,1,1,1,1,1,[]));
r7= permute(r6, 7:-1:1);
A=reshape((1e6:1e7-1), size(r7));
A(A==r7)
toc

(*
ans =

     1741725
     4210818
     9800817
     9926315
*)
```

Comment: Why `.^7`? Shouldn't it be `.^3`?

Comment: @LuisMendo No, the power is equal to the integer length.

Comment: Can't you replace all you `reshape(m,1,1,[])` things with `m(:)` and then just call `r1'` and `r2'` etc?

Comment: @Mathe Then you should change the definition at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code in two ways:

1. You can reverse the order in which you compute the sum of powers. This lets you do away with the (expensive) permutation at the end.
2. You can then use the first intermediate value to do two sums at once.
3. You can also flatten the result at each step to avoid higher-dimensional arrays. This also lets you avoid the reshaping of A at the end.
4. You can use an inline function to simplify notation.

This results in:

```
tic
m1=(1:9).^7;
m=(0:9).^7;
combine = @(x,y) reshape(bsxfun(@plus, x, y'),[],1);
r2=combine(m, m);
r4=combine(r2, r2);
r6=combine(r4, r2);
r7=combine(r6, m1')';
r7(r7 == (1e6:1e7-1))'
toc
```

You'll find this is significantly faster as well.

You can make this generic over N by using the same trick used when computing integer powers:

```
function a = andy(N)
m1=uint32((1:9).^N);
m=uint32((0:9)'.^N);
k = uint32(N) - 1;
result = uint32(0);
combine = @(x,y) reshape(bsxfun(@plus, x, y'),[],1);
while (1),
    if (bitand(k, 1) ~= 0), result = combine(result,m); end
    k = bitshift(k,-1);
    if (k == 0), break, end
    m = combine(m,m);
end
result = combine(result,m1')';
a = result(result == ((10^(N-1)):(10^N-1)))';
```

I converted all values to `uint32`, which is not only 20% faster, but also allowed me to compute the 9-digit Anderson numbers:

```
>> tic,andy(9),toc

ans =

   146511208
   472335975
   534494836
   912985153

Elapsed time is 40.208217 seconds.
```

Computing 10 digit Anderson numbers would require `uint64` and is beyond the memory capabilities of my machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `shiftdim` instead of `reshape` and put `bsxfun` in a for loop

```
m=(0:9).^7.';
r=(1:9).^7.';
for k=1:6,
    m = shiftdim(m,-1);
    r = bsxfun(@plus, r, m);
end
r= permute(r, 7:-1:1);
A=reshape((1e6:1e7-1), size(r7));
A(A==r7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to do it, quite compact but will still require some updating for arbitrary lengths. However, I guess you won't be able to compute numbers for many different lengths anyway.

```
[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7] = ndgrid(0:9);

V = X1.^7+ X2.^7+ X3.^7+ X4.^7+ X5.^7+ X6.^7+ X7.^7;
W = X1*1e6+ X2*1e5+ X3*1e4+ X4*1e3+ X5*1e2+ X6*1e1+ X7;
W(W==V&X1>0)
```

Comment: For those thinking about it: Using a `num2str` based approach will be much slower.